# Unable to select all rows of information_schema.triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two kinds of users in my Postgres database. One has access to everything in the database and has admin access. The other kind has `SELECT` access on public schema and `USAGE` access on information_schema.

When I run the following query, the second kind of user sees only a subset of all results which the first kind of user can see.

```sql
SELECT action_statement, event_object_table 
FROM information_schema.triggers;
```

I am not able to understand what could be happening here. Triggers on the table from same public schema are present, but miraculously some triggers are missing for other tables in the same public schema.

Comment: From the docs [information_schema.triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-triggers.html): *The view triggers contains all triggers defined in the current database on tables and views that the current user owns or has some privilege other than SELECT on.*